# Preventing classes from being instantiated on the stack or as data member

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I'm starting to use shared pointers in C++ (Visual Studio 2010) and run into the following problem.

I am writing a new module which defines an interface that tells the module how to behave in certain conditions.  It's something like this (artifical example just to illustrate my problem):

```
// Interface that should be implemented by user of the module
class RingAlert
   {
   public:
      virtual void ring() = 0;
   };

// Module that does something important
class Module
   {
   public:
      Module (RingAlert &ringAlert) : m_ringAlert(ringAlert) {}
      void dosomething();   // may call RingAlert::ring if something goes wrong.
   private:
      RingAlert &m_ringAlert;
   };
```

To make it easy for the users of the module, and because the RingAlert could be passed to other modules as well, I am now making this a shared pointer, like this:

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<RingAlert> RingAlertPtr;

class Module
   {
   public:
      Module (RingAlertPtr ringAlert) : m_ringAlert(ringAlert) {}
      void dosomething();   // may call RingAlert::ring if something goes wrong.
   private:
      RingAlertPtr m_ringAlert;
   };
```

Now users of the module may create a new RingAlert instance and simply pass it to the module, without keeping it somewhere and deleting it at the end of the application.

The problem starts if the application does something like this:

```
class MyRingAlert : public RingAlert
   {
   public:
      virtual void ring() {std::cout << "ring ring" << std::endl;}
   };

class Application
   {
   public:
   private:
      MyRingAlert m_myRingAlert;
   };

// later, somewhere in application code
Module m(RingAlertPtr(&m_myRingAlert));
```

In this example, the application takes the address of a data member and puts it in a shared pointer.
Later in the application, the destructor of the Module will delete the shared pointer, which will decrement the reference count, and which will then **delete** the ring alert, which mustn't be deleted because it is a data member of the Application class.

I found a way of preventing the shared pointer from deleting the instance by doing this (using lambda's but also have a slightly cleaner solution using a function):

```
Module m(RingAlertPtr(&m_myRingAlert,[](void *){});
```

Although this solves my problem, I'm not completely happy with it because it will still give a problem if the Application class is destructed before the Module class.

The only good solution seems to be to **force** the rest of the application to **new** the instance of RingAlert (or actually the class that implements RingAlert).

Can this be done?
Is there a way to prevent code from instantiating subclasses of a base class on the stack or as datamember?
In other words: can we force subclasses of a base class being newed if they want to be instantiated?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enforce users to create objects of class derived from mine with "new" only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833752/how-to-enforce-users-to-create-objects-of-class-derived-from-mine-with-new-only)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fundamentally flawed- what if I want my main class to inherit and provide that callback? You're artificially limiting it for no real advantage. Use a `std::function` instead.

```
class Module {
public:
    Module (std::function<void()> ringAlert) : Alert(ringAlert) {}
    void dosomething() {
        if (something) alert();
    }  
private:
    std::function<void()> alert;
};
```

The Standard function type is exceedingly flexible and very good to use.

You could also provide for a custom destruction function.

```
class Module {
public:
    Module(interface* ptr, std::function<void(interface*)> destructor)
        :pointer(ptr), destruct(destructor) {
    }
    ~Module() {
        if (destruct)
            destruct(pointer);
    }
    void doSomething() {
        if (condition)
            pointer->ring();
    }
private:
    interface* pointer;
    std::function<void(interface*)> destruct;
};
```

If I alloc on the stack, I pass an empty function object. If I allocate on the heap, I pass a quick destruction lambda.

Comment: To make the example easy, I only added one method in the interface.  In practice there will be multiple methods in the interface, so using function-pointers, functors or lambda's is not sufficient.

Comment: @Patrick: Why not? It's more code to inherit from an interface and define all it's members than it is to assign to that many function objects.

Comment: Nice idea.  I'll further look at it.

Answer (score 1):

What I tend to do - and it's by no means the right way - or even the best way is as follows:

```
struct IType
{
    typedef shared_ptr<IType> Ptr;

    virtual DoSomething( ) = 0;

protected:
    virtual ~IType( ) { }
};

class Type : public IType
{
public:
    typedef shared_ptr<Type> Ptr;

    static Ptr New( )
    {
        return Ptr( 
                   new Type( ),
                   &Type::Delete
                  );
    }

private:

    virtual void DoSomething( );

    Type( ); // Defined in the CPP file.

    static void Delete( Type* p )
    {
        delete ( p );
    }
};
```

So you can only ever create an object of type Type::Ptr, You cannot delete the enclosed type through the .get() method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works if your class is a rather 'stand-alone' class.  In my case, I also want to force all subclass instantiations to be created using new.

Comment: Actually I tend to use this model for hierarchies of classes and interfaces. There's nothing in it which prevents its use as such.

Answer (score 0):

What about to create private type-depended overrides operator `new` and `delete` for class RingAlert

Answer (score 0):

I believe the usual solution to make the constructor(s) `protected` and only allow creation through `static` (or free `friend` functions) returning `shared_ptr<>`. Since the constructor is protected, non-friend code cannot create instances, whether that code tries to construct the instance on the stack or, in a constructor, as a member.

You have to ensure that child classes also make their constructors protected, of course.

Comment: That's my point.  How can I enforce this for all child classes as well?

Comment: I don't think you can as a matter of source code. However, you do have unit tests and documentation as resources to enforce behaviour. Provide a templated unit test which fails to compile if the child class won't play nice. Document it.

Answer (score 0):

Make the constructor for `RingAlert` private and create a static method that calls `new` and returns the pointer (or better yet, returns the `shared_ptr`).